# Are there alternative repositories for ruby1.8 package in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, ruby

I want to upgrade existing Ruby 1.8.7 package to patchlevel 300+ revision. Official repository version is this one:

> ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249)

Are there any repositories that provided 1.8.7 updates at some point? I know about RVM, but I'd like to have more fresh version to be installed for all users by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this, since I'm on Oneiric and that version is already 300+, but you can try to search for PPAs by using: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas (sometimes it is a bit slow).

I've already tried a quick search for [„ruby1.8 lucid”](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=ruby1.8%20lucid):

- [Redmine PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/redmine/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) for example contains `ruby1.8 1.8.7.357-1~lucid+2`

Be careful though when using PPAs, general precautions apply.